# How to writing values from 2 separate data tables across two worksheets in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that has several predefined data tables. I Need to copy specific column values and insert into another predefined table on a different worksheet. if I can get this to work on one I can get the rest. Ive seen similar posts but they are not moving from a predefined table to another (from ribbon: Insert>Table). the below VBA Code in the module throws "Object doesnt support this property or method." im assuming the ListObject Object cant call a cell the way this is calling it. not sure how to insert that data into that row.

```
  Sub Search_and_Copy_Invoices()
    '  Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {DEL}"

     Dim tbl As ListObject
     Dim tblDest As ListObject
     Dim lrow As Range
     Dim RowNum As Long

     RowNum = 0

    Set tbl = Sheet3.ListObjects("tbl_Invoices")
    Set tblDest = Sheet4.ListObjects("tbl_Quarter1")

    For Each lrow In tbl.ListColumns("Invoice#").DataBodyRange.Rows
       ' Debug.Print "Invoice" & vbTab & lrow.Offset(0, 2) & vbTab & lrow.Offset(0, 5)
       tblDest.Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = "Invoice"
       tblDest.Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = lrow.Offset(0, 2)
       tblDest.Cells(RowNum, 3).Value = lrow.Offset(0, 5)
     
       RowNum = RowNum + 1
    Next lrow
    RowNum = 0
 End Sub
```

Another potential issue is inserting the other datatable data into that same table, i dont want to replace the data just append to it.  and i need to clear that table every time the method calling all these subroutines is executed.

Comment: There is no `Cells` property of a `ListObject`.

Comment: `RowNum = 0`: there's no row 0. Rows always begin at 1.

Comment: Why not just copy the entire `ListColumn`, instead of looping?

Comment: i changed the rowNum  to 1. what is the propery used to insert? i used " .InsertRowRange(RowNum, 1).Value = "Invoice"" but its throwing "Object variable or With Block variable not set" used a with tblDest block and still throwing same error

Comment: `insertrowrange` is a read only property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.insertrowrange

Comment: @andras They're probably default code names.

Comment: Yeah those are the default excel designations for the worksheets.

Comment: Perhaps replace `tblDest.Cells(RowNum, 1).Value` by `tblDest.DataBodyRange.Cells(RowNum, 1).Value` ? Is `RowNum` set 0 in the first place to Name the Table Header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these lines in your `For Each` loop starting with:

```
tblDest.Cells(RowNum, 1).Value ...
```

Should rather be like this:

```
tblDest.DataBodyRange.Cells(RowNum, 1).Value ...
```